# php session variables not working on live server

Tags: php, session

I have developed a website in php in which I have a login form that checks user's authentication using user name and password.

The pages to be accessible only by authenticated users checks session variables either true or false. These variables are set to true if username and password of user are true and I have set that during login check and so users can't access webpages by directly writing page name in URL.

This works fine on local host but fails on live server,   somebody plz help me

Comment: edit your question and add your code in it as @KarthickKumarGanesh told.

Answer (score 0):

Issues

1) database may not connecting properly,

or 2) session save path at tmp folder is not writable.

Comment: First one is not the problem so I think its second one can u tell me what should I do to store session variables on pemenent folder?